heavy dirt in the concave corners
How can I make heavy dirt, in the concave corners and edges of a mesh (like the blue triangle in the image), with particles?

thanks
I have a new problem:
How can I have dirt on the convex edges of the corners like in the blue circle in the cube image where the dirt did not appear (still using the graph from: Markus von Broady with the image below)?

thanks

Maybe a setup like this can work for you:

It makes a copy of your object, smooths it, and overlaps with the original object. If the topology (wireframe) of your mesh isn't even, smoothing will also not be even and the effect will be ugly. Also if there's not enough density, smoothing just won't do much - e.g. you can't smooth the default cube. To combat these problems, I remesh by converting the mesh to volume and back to mesh. Remeshing is slow, however, so ideally you would prepare your mesh so that the "volume" nodes can be muted.
The problem with overlapping geometry is that it has "perfect" (sharp) creases where the surfaces meet. You could join both and remesh again, and smooth, or if you prepared the input geometry so that you don't need remesh, you could use boolean union, then smooth - but boolean will produce ngons which may not smooth that well so you may need to remesh after all...
If you want to affect only a part of the object, you need to separate it first, using boolean or just "Separate Geometry" node, depending if you remesh next or boolean next (boolean needs manifold topology).


Thank you for your help
I have more questions:
How can I smooth the dirt mesh faces?
Is there a way to smooth the transition between the object and the dirt?
thank you again

Is it possible to choose, with selection, which part of the object will receive the dirt?

@Markus could you add to your answers a rough textual description of the used principles and workflow, maybe include the names of key intervening the nodes, so the they are indexed and the answer can be found through searching? Thanks

I didn't understand anything you wrote above.
I don't understand much about geometry nodes, I'm learning.
For now, my doubts are these above in the comments.
I really like your solution and would just like a few more configurations.
can you help me
Thanks in advance

Is it possible to choose, with selection, which part of the object will receive the dirt?
Could you send me the graph?
thank you very much

I have a new problem described in the initial post. Can anyone help me?
